# Angular Material tab group not updating in Front end HTML using Angular Services

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, angular-services

I am having two components name called Sibling1Component and Sibling2Component.
Sibling1Component having BreadCrumbs and when clicking on BreadCrumb value I need to change the Sibling2Component Material Group.
With the help of service I am trying to change the Sibling2Component Mat Group values but it's not working.

> Sibling2Component HTML

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs [selectedIndex]="tabGroup">
  <mat-tab style="font-size:14px;" label="All"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab style="font-size:14px;"  label="Real Time"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="freq" label="Daily"></mat-tab>                 
</mat-tab-group>
```

> Siblin2Component.ts

```
constructor(private _sharedService: ProcessService) {    
  this._sharedService.selectedTabAll.subscribe((value)=> {
    this.selectTab(value);           
  });
}

selectTab(index: number) {    
  this.tabGroup = index;    
}
```

> Sibling1Component.ts

```
public onBreadCrumbChangeProcess() {    
  this._sharedService.setSelectedTabAll(0);
}
```

> ProcessService.ts

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ProcessService {

  public static isSelectedTabAll = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  selectedTabAll = ProcessService.isSelectedTabAll.asObservable();

  public setSelectedTabAll(flag: any) {
    ProcessService.isSelectedTabAll.next(flag);
  }

}
```

Is anything i had missed to call Sibling2Component2 from Sibling1Component?